# Hibernate query is not retriving the result?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

Here is bean class,

```
@Entity
@Table(name="hlatlng")
public class HistoryLatitudeBean {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "id")
private int id;
@Column(name="vehicleno")
private int vehicleno;
@Column(name="lat")
private String lat;
@Column(name="lng")
private String lng;
@Column(name="status")
private String status;
@Column(name="rdate")
private Date rdate;
@Column(name="rtime")
private Date rtime;
//getter setter,
}
```

In Hibernate method I am writing,

```
          Map<String, Object> parameterNameAndValues = new HashMap<String, Object>();

          parameterNameAndValues.put("vehicleno", 12);
          parameterNameAndValues.put("frmdate", frmDate);
          parameterNameAndValues.put("todate", toDate);

          hql= "from HistoryLatitudeBean where vehicleno=:vehicleno and rdate BETWEEN :frmdate and :todate";
          Query query =session.createQuery(hql);
            /*query.setParameter("vehicleno", 12);
            query.setParameter("frmdate", frmDate);
            query.setParameter("todate", toDate);*/


          for (Entry<String, Object> e : parameterNameAndValues.entrySet()) {
                query.setParameter(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
            }

            List<HistoryLatitudeBean> groupList = (List<HistoryLatitudeBean>)query.list();

            //Here groupList contains null              

             for(HistoryLatitudeBean arr : groupList){
                 vehicleHistoryList.add(arr);    
                 System.out.println("List :"+arr.getLat());
                }


             transaction.commit();
```

Problem is `query.list()` method returns null.
The same query I am trying in mysql db as,
`SELECT * FROM hlatlng WHERE vehicleno='12' AND rdate BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-09-01';`

and my table structure is like this,

```
CREATE TABLE `hlatlng` (
 `vehicleno` int(40) DEFAULT NULL,
 `lat` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
 `lng` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
 `status` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
 `rdate` date DEFAULT NULL,
 `rtime` date DEFAULT NULL,
 `id` int(40) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

It gives me 3 rows. I am not getting what is  wrong in my code , can any one help me in this please.

Comment: Could you add a trace to make sure you pass the right parameters to your query: `System.out.println('Param: ' e.getKey() +" => " + e.getValue() );` in your param assignation loop? (the 12 must be OK, but the dates?)

Comment: Please add some detailed error message cant understand what is the issue i think map contain some extra value ...

Comment: add `@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)` to the date fields.

Comment: `@Column(name="rdate") @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date rdate;`

Comment: ooh.. I thought you are using hibernate with JPA. I will try to find the equivalent annotations.. the problem would be that the dates are not interpreted properly

Comment: Ooh.. that's strange, even I couldnt see any issues which causes this problem unless you are passing some dates which doesnt have any data in db. You can add `@Type(type="date")` to your date fields once and check.

Comment: Why don't you check hibernate query what is getting queried from database and try with them, using show_sql true. it will help to debug where the result is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Date` in java will have the time part associated with it. If our data is only on dates, we need to trim the time part.

Adding the `@Type(type="date")` will take care of this while sending it to the database.

I tried to find a reference, unfortunately I could not find anything.